# Could not generate a proxy class ContractVerifierExtension in Spring Cloud Contract

Tags: spring-cloud-contract

I'm following the [basic setup under Gradle project](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-contract/2.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#gradle-project). Getting this error:

```
* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.springframework.cloud.contract', version: '2.2.0.RELEASE']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.springframework.cloud.contract']
   > Could not generate a proxy class for class org.springframework.cloud.contract.verifier.plugin.ContractVerifierExtension.
```

Related stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/provider/MapProperty
```

Is there some gradle version requirement? I am currently on Gradle 4.9. Or some other reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of gradle is wrong. Please use the latest 5.x version.

Comment: Where I can get doc about min version of Gradle for this plugin?

Comment: Currently the way to check it out is to go to the code https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-contract/blob/v2.2.2.RELEASE/spring-cloud-contract-tools/spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties#L3